# VisualBoyAdvance Battery Has Run Dry

Tags: emulation, realtime

I recently downloaded VBA and Pokemon Emerald. The game says "The Internal Battery has run dry" I've been told to go to Options>Emulator>Real Time Clock, but there is no clock! I have checked everywhere and tried multiple other fixes, but nothing works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it from the terminal.

`vba --rtc yourromfile.gba`

If it works, there must be something wrong with your configuration in the graphical version.  You can play with it more or just start running VBA from the terminal.

If you want a full list of options you can give VBA, type `man vba`.  There's more stuff in there than in the graphical version.